# Query to get tables created on a particular date

Tags: mysql

Hi here my interest is to get all the tables which are created on a particular date irrespective of time when it has been created for this in order to get created time for the list of tables I have tried:

```
select table_name,create_time 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema='database_name'
```

and I have got the result as

```
| Table_name                       | 2012-09-13 03:09:50 |  
| Table_name                       | 2012-10-01 08:05:41 |
| Table_name                       | 2012-10-01 08:05:41 |
| temp                             | 2011-05-25 03:05:50 |
```

Now I need to get the tables which are created on 2012-10-01 for this I have tried:

```
select table_name,create_time 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema='database_name' and create_time='2012-10-01'
```

and I am getting the result `Empty set (5.09 sec)`.

Here I need to get all the tables which are created on 2012-10-01 irrespective of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name,create_time FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='quadv2_dev' AND DATE_FORMAT(create_time,'%Y-%m-%d')='2012-09-17'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT table_name,create_time 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema='database_name' AND
    create_time BETWEEN '2012-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-10-01 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 1):

As we already have other options. Please see if below can help you.

You can simply use [like](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) to get tables created on particular date, worked well for.

```
select table_name,create_time  from information_schema.tables  where table_schema='dbname' AND (create_time like "2012-10-01 %");
```

Hope this help !!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there is a better way, but this seems to be working for me:

```
SELECT table_name,create_time from information_schema.tables
where table_schema='database_name'
AND create_time BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND DATE_ADD('2012-10-02', INTERVAL -1 SECOND)
```